# PHPmailer issue - php coding above html but not receiving emails

Tags: php, html, phpmailer, contacts, contact-form

I'm trying to use phpmailer to work alongside a contact form I have made. I was originally using simple php coding for the form, but this would not work on the web company's server, so they asked me to use phpmailer instead. I have changed the coding a little bit to try and integrate it into the contact page that has the contact form.

```
<?php
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.live.com';                            // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->Username = "myemail@hotmail.com";
$mail->Password = "mypassword";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->addAddress('stacey_victoria@hotmail.com', 'Sender');     // Add a recipient

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Message from Website';
$mail->Body    = $message; $name;
$mail->From    = $email;

if($_POST){
$feedback = 'Thanks for your message';

}

?>
```

The contact page appears as normal, and once the submit button has been pressed, the echo-feedback message is shown. However, no email is sent through.

I edited the "Simple Example" found here: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer and uploaded the php file to the server and this worked fine so I know the smtp information I have used is correct and working.

Is it even possible to put phpmailer coding above the html coding?

If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you did not follow the 'Simple Example' ie `$mail->From    = $email;` is not correct `$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');` is.  Go back and try again.

Comment: Not true. You can set the `From` property directly, or via the `setFrom()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending the email...
Use :

```
if($mail->Send())
```